# Live View Map not showing requests

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am running it on localhost (XAMPP) on my Mac, i went to localhost:3000 and devtools console is not showing errors but when i try to load a page is not showing it on index.html map. my logs folder is correct, port is 3000,  Maybe someone can figure out about it: https://github.com/nomisoft/rtwv-map

```
config.js

var config = {}

// Port to run the application on
config.port = 3000;

// Log file format - either combined or common
config.logformat = 'combined';

// Directory of the log files to parse
config.logdir = '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/logs/';

// Debugging mode outputs details to console - either true or false
config.debug = true;

module.exports = config;
```

```
frontend.js

$(document).ready(function() {

    var routes = new Array();
    var socket = io();

    var currentWidth = $('#map').width();
    var width = 938;
    var height = 620;

    var projection = d3.geo.mercator().scale(150).translate([width / 2, height / 1.41]);

    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

    var svg = d3.select("#map")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid")
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
        .attr("width", currentWidth)
        .attr("height", currentWidth * height / width);


    queue().defer(d3.json, "countries.json")
        .await(function(error, countries) {
            svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "countries")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(topojson.feature(countries, countries.objects.countries).features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path);
        });

    socket.on('visitor', function(json){
        $('#visits').append( 
            $('<tr>').append( $('<td>').text(json.visitor.ip) )
                .append( $('<td>').text(json.status) )
                .append( $('<td>').text(json.url) )
        );

        if( $('#visits').height() > $(window).height() ) {
            $('#visits tbody tr:first').remove();
        }

        route = svg.append("path")
            .datum({type: "LineString", coordinates: [ [json.visitor.geo[1],json.visitor.geo[0]], [json.server.geo[1],json.server.geo[0]] ]})
            .attr("class", "route route-"+json.status)
            .attr("d", path);  

        var totalLength = route.node().getTotalLength();

        route.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
            .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .ease("linear")
            .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

        var key = routes.length;
        routes[ key ] = route;

        setTimeout(function(key) {
            routes[key].style("opacity", 1).transition().duration(5000).style("opacity", 0).remove();
            routes[key] = null;
        }, 2000, key);

    });

});
```

```
index.js

// Import config variables
var config = require('./config');
// Import Express framework
var app = require('express')();
// Import the http module
var http = require('http').Server(app);
// Import socket.io library
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
// Import GeoIP library for converting IP's to locations
var geoip = require('geoip-lite');
// Import os module for detecting network interfaces
var os = require('os');
// Import filesystem module
var fs = require('fs');
// Import child process module for running tail in a child process
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

io.set('origins', '*:*');

// Get the IP address of the server
var addresses = [];
var interfaces = os.networkInterfaces();
for(var k in interfaces) {
    for(var k2 in interfaces[k]) {
        var address = interfaces[k][k2];
        if (address.family === 'IPv4' && !address.internal) {
            addresses.push(address.address);
        }
    }
}

var tail;
// Array to hold list of files to tail
var logfiles = [];
// Loop through all the files in the given folder
fs.readdir(config.logdir, function(err, files) {
    if( files instanceof Array ) {
        files.forEach(function(filename){
            if( config.debug ) {
                console.log('Tailing ' + filename);
            }
            logfiles.push(config.logdir + filename);
        });
        // Tail all the files in our logfiles array    
        tail = spawn("tail", ["-f"].concat(logfiles));
    } else {
        console.log('No log files found');
    }
});


// Request to load the homepage
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
// Request to load the countries json file
app.get('/countries.json', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/countries.json');
});
// Request to load stylesheet
app.get('/style.css', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/style.css');
});
// Request to front end javascript file
app.get('/frontend.js', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/frontend.js');
});

// Bind function to io connection event
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    // When a new line is found in the tailed files
    tail.stdout.on("data", function (data) {


        console.log('Connected to Socket.IO');
        // For each new line
        var lines = data.toString().split(/(\r?\n)/g);
        lines.forEach(function(line) {

            // Perform regular expression match on the new line
            if( config.logformat == 'combined' ) {
                var format = /^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\[[^\]]+\]) ("[^"]+") (\d+) (\d+) ("[^"]*") ("[^"]*").*$/;
            } else {
                var format = /^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\[[^\]]+\]) ("[^"]+") (\d+) (\d+)$/;
            }
            var visit = line.match(format);

            if( visit != null && ( visit.length == 7 || visit.length == 10 ) ) {


                console.log('new');
            
                // Perform regular expression match on the request section of the log
                var request = visit[5].match(/^"(GET|POST|OPTIONS|HEAD)+ (\S+) HTTP\/1.\d+"$/);

                // if request is to a page (not image/css/js etc)
                var extension = request[2].match(/\.([0-9a-z])+$/i);
                var exclusions = ["jpg","gif","js","css","bmp","svg","exe","mp4","mpg","mov","ico"];
                if( extension == null || exclusions.indexOf(extension[1]) == -1 ) {

                    // get lat/lng for ip address
                    var geo = geoip.lookup(visit[1]);
                    var server_geo = geoip.lookup(addresses[0]);

                    // Create json to output to the browser
                    var data = { 
                        'status': visit[6],
                        'url': request[2],
                        'visitor': {
                            'ip': visit[1],
                            'geo': (geo != null && 'll' in geo) ? geo.ll : [0,0]
                        },
                        'server': {
                            'ip': addresses[0],
                            'geo': (server_geo != null && 'll' in server_geo) ? server_geo.ll : [0,0]
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // Send data to the browser
                    io.emit('visitor', data);
                    if( config.debug ) {
                        console.log('Sending for '+line);
                    }
                }
            }

        });

    });
});

// Open a connection listening on chosen port
http.listen(config.port, function(){
    if( config.debug ) {
        console.log('listening on *:'+config.port);
    }
});
```

```
index.html

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Real-Time Website Visitors Map</title>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <table id="visits">
        <thead>
            <th>IP</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Request</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.1.3/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="frontend.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```